# 407 Proxy Authentication Required in Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, numpy, proxy

I am trying to install `numpy` in windows 8.1 using `pip install numpy`.

It gives following error:

```
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connectio
n failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connectio
n failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connectio
n failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connectio
n failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connectio
n failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions:
)
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

After referring [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_5) I run following command in `cmd`:

```
set proxy proxy-server="http=202.141.80.19:3128;https=202.141.80.19:3128"
```

For authentication purpose I have also tried:

```
set proxy proxy-server="http=username:password@202.141.80.19:3128;https=username:password@202.141.80.19:3128"
```

But it did not work.

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: `netsh` is not the same thing as `cmd`.  The documentation you link to is for `netsh`.  Besides, numpy probably doesn't use WinHTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many attempts this helped me proceed with my work.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```